# jquery play stop audio file

Tags: jquery, audio, toggle

I have a list of songs and the way im using to access them is :

```
<a href="path to song 1">play</a>
<a href="path to song 2">play</a>
...
```

when  the link is clicked, the song starts and im doing this with jquery like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
    var path = $(this).attr('href');
    var song = new Audio(path);
    song.play();
});
```

How can i make a play/stop toggle when the link is clicked?

Answer (score 1):

Toggle `play()` and `pause()` functions like this:

```js
var isPlaying = false
$("a").on("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var path = $(this).attr('href');
  var song = new Audio(path);

  if (!isPlaying) {
    isPlaying = true;
    song.play();
    $(this).text("Pause")
  } else {
    isPlaying = false;
    song.pause();
    $(this).text("Play");
  }

  console.log(isPlaying);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<a href="path to song 1">play</a>
<a href="path to song 2">play</a>
```

Comment: Tks @Pedram. This i think, pointed me to the right direction =) Just had to change one or two things and its working.